# Android JUnit: How to have an exception cause a test case to pass (@Test annotation)

Tags: java, android, exception, junit

I'm trying to write some JUnit tests for an Android application.

I've read online that to have a unit test pass if it throws an exception, you would use the @Test annotation like this

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullValue() throws Throwable
{
    Object o = null;
    o.toString();
}
```

but Eclipse is telling me that this annotation doesn't exist. How can I fix this? If I run the test, it runs fine and fails as expected but obviously I want it to fail (and thus actually pass) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always bypass it manually:

```
public void testNullValue()
{
    try {
       Object o = null;
       o.toString();
       fail("Expected NullPointerException to be thrown");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this seems like it would work, I don't know if it makes sense to replicate what should be a built in feature. Thanks though

Comment: It makes sense if you want to test out what's in the catch block for one. + I think that pre-annotations this would have been the way to do it. I haven't used JUnit all that long though so I may well be wrong..

Comment: Yes, this is the correct pattern to use for testing on Android, which uses JUnit 3.  (The annotations are only available in JUnit 4)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that Android uses JUnit 3. Thanks Aaron.

Comment: `assertTrue(true)` isn't very useful. Can just do nothing there instead.

Comment: @ColinD - that's the way I originally had it. But I think this way demonstrates that's where the code you are testing as the successful path through the test belongs. In this case that's blank as you pointed out

Answer (score 3):

I believe that should be:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
```

Comment: That is correct, I simply mistyped that. However that doesn't solve the problem. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Do you have an import for the Test annotation?  And are you using JUnit 4.x?  (I know at some point with one version of Eclipse, it somehow switched me to Junit 3.x, which I *think* doesn't support annotations.)  Something to check anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I imported the JUnit 4 library and now the compiler allows me to use the @Test annotation. Unfortunately, when I try to run the test it gives me the error "Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'"

Comment: Does it say which class is missing?

Comment: The question clearly says it's about testing an **android** application.  Testing with the Android SDK uses JUnit 3.

Comment: I wondered about that.  Then annotations aren't available.  You'll have to use the work-around filip-fku mentions in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check the JUnit version you are using
2. Do not use the JUnit that eclipse provides (Indigo) but import manually a JUnit 4.9 manually

The error is that "mysterious" error that has not an easy or immediate answer, I am only trying ideas